# IIS Rewrite to replace string in URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to implement an IIS redirect that is basically a string replace.

Here I what to change old to new.  The other parts of the URL should not change and they can be in different formats.

localhost://part1/old/part2/something-old

to

localhost://part1/new/part2/something-new

and

localhost://part1/old/part2/part3/nothing-old

to

localhost://part1/new/part2/part3/nothing-new

Comment: I should have mentioned in my post.  There are many thousands of variations, so writing a rule for each occurrence of a particular URL would be painful.

Comment: Depending on the URL example you give is not the correct URL, usually for your purposes you can use the pattern to match, then capture the old and something-old parts and rewrite them.